# Looping through an array and split by comma python

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
#target_filename

base_source_dir = 'C:\\SourceFiles\\'
base_target_dir = 'C:\\TargetFiles\\'


###read the filename_convention.txt file and put it into an array'
parserlines = [line.strip().split(",") for line in open("C:\\Python34\\filename_convention.txt", 'r')]


parserarray = 'loop through each line from the array parserlines and split by comma'
   # account for the headerline
```

Ok so I have a file with a list basically like this

```
matt, bob, john
susan, matt, larry
joe, bob, susan
```

I want to read a line[] then be able to get the individual names.

I am new to python so any help is appreciated!

Comment: your question is not clear you have already splitted on comma what more do you want

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? The list (what you call array is called list in python) does not contain any commas. Also there is no headerline. You actually have all individual names, although in a nested list, which you could flatten. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: do you need to read from the file, as you already do, or from the parsed array?

Comment: Ok so i have parserlines to read the file and put it into an array.

Comment: I wanted to use parserarray to then loop through that particular line and give me the individual names.

Comment: Like parserlines[2], parserarray[1] would give me the 3rd line and 2nd value

Comment: already you have split the lines at comma what more do you need

Comment: I need parserarray[2] to give me the second value within the array.

Comment: source_dir,source_pattern,target_dir,prefix
ack_nak,2:I101,F21,MT101-
ack_nak,2:O101,F21,MT101-
ack_nak,2:I103,F21,MT103-
ack_nak,2:O103,F21,MT103-
mt195,2:I195,mt,MT195-
mt195,2:O195,mt,MT195-
mtx99,2:I199,mt,MT199-
mtx99,2:O199,mt,MT199-
incomplete--

Answer (score 0):

```
names=[]
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        names+=line.split(", ")
```